# Как через WMI я могу получить Site Bindings?

Tags: iis, wmi

В общем, если в настройках IIS щелкнуть правой кнопкой по сайту, то можно зайти в такую настройку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, а как я это могу получить через WMI?

У объектов объекта IISWebServerSetting есть подобное свойство со списком, но там информация не такая, как я вижу тут...

Похоже на то, что возвращается только первый бинд..

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нашел решение...
Нужно в пространстве `WebAdministration`, сделать запрос `SELECT * FROM Site`.

Далее, в каждом возвращенном объекте будет коллекция `Bindings` и вот там будут свойства `BindingInformation` и `Protocol`.